# How to concatenate strings and numbers and prevent Lua from converting the result into a string?

Tags: lua

To summarize, what I'm trying to do is acces to the fourth element of an array (table) named `ap` every time the program receives through socket communication the message `ap[4]`.

In order to achieve that, the program, once the message has arrived, calls to a function that *"takes"* the char `4` and converts it into a number.

Till now, everything is perfect, but when I try to concatenate the `4` number again between `ap[` and `]`, Lua converts everything to a string again. I know that this is a typical behaviour of Lua, but I REALLY can't find the way to solve this problem.

Hope you can help me. Thanks.

```
--Have this:
message = "ap[4]"

--Want this:
valueMessage = ap[4]
```

Comment: Thanks @EgorSkriptunoff this is exactly what I was looking for. You are awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of converting `ap[4]` to a number you can use `loadstring` to execute it.

Example:

```
ap = {[4] = 'Hello World'}
message = "ap[4]"
get_valueMessage = loadstring("return " .. message)

print(get_valueMessage())
```

This method offers flexibility when working with tables of variable depth.
If your working with tables that have consistent depth Egor Skriptunoff answer is a better solution

The table would need to be global for the loadstring function to access it.

Something to keep in mind, about this method, is it also offers an injection path for malicious code, as it is executing the message. If the message contains something other then a table index such as function call, it can be exploited. The `return` added to the message does mitigate some of the shenanigans.

Comment: That doesn't work, since `ap` is local, and the compiled chunk cannot access it.

Comment: Ah dang i had tested it without the local in my ide. edited answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

```
name="ap"; idx=4; value=_G[name][idx]
```